# How do I split up an array while still selecting all items?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have an array of fruits and an empty basket array. I push the fruits to the basket and loop through the basket in the template. I can output the whole array of fruits inside the basket.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="fruit in basket">
       <li>{{ fruit }}</li>
    </div>
    <button @click="addFruit">Add to basket</button>
 </template>
    
<script>
     data() {
      return {
        fruits: ['Orange', 'Apple'],
        basket: [],
      };
    },
   methods: {
      addFruit() {
        this.basket.push(this.fruits);
      },
     }
</script>
```

But what if I want each individual fruit to be shown as a list item? As it is right now I output the entire array of fruits.
I know that I can easilly get the individual fruits by saying

```
<li>{{ fruit[0] }}</li>
```

But that would not be practical as it requires a lot of manual work.

When I am pushing the fruits, I am looking for a way to also split them up, so that when I fire the addFruit function, I add all the fruits, but I add them as individual items.

I know there are other ways to do this, but I specifially want to know how I do this while keeping the arrays and the push method.

EDIT: I tried to write the fruit example because I wanted to keep it as simple as possible, but I will include my own code then.

In my code, I fetch an array of data from my database. I store the data results in a const called recipients. That is then pushed into an array called defaultTags. So I push an array of data into an empty array, in this case a list of emails and other contact information, which is then outputted as a tag, but what I want is to actually output the data as individual items. So instead of having one big tag that stores the whole array. Eg: [email1, email2, email3], I wish to have a seperate tag for each email in the array.

```
 load() {
    switch (this.entityType) {
      case 'TENANCY':
        userService.getCurrentUser().then(userResult => {
          tenancyService.getTenants(this.entityId).then(result => {
            const defaultTags = [];
            const recipients = result.data
              .map(tenant => tenant.legalEntity)
              .filter(legalEntity => legalEntity.email || (!legalEntity.email && this.asNotification ? legalEntity.name : null))
              .map(legalEntity => ({
                emailAddress: legalEntity.email || (!legalEntity.email && this.asNotification ? legalEntity.name.concat(' ', `(${this.$t('letterMail').toLowerCase()})`) : null),
                legalEntityId: legalEntity.id
              }));
            if (recipients.length) {
              defaultTags.push(this.setText({description: this.$t('tenants'), recipients}));
            }
            this.autocompleteItems.push(...defaultTags);
            if (this.includeUser) {
              defaultTags.push(this.setText({
                description: this.$t('user'),
                recipients: [{emailAddress: userResult.data.email}]
              }));
            }
            if (this.prefill) {
              this.tagsChanged(defaultTags);
            }
            tenancyService.getUnits(this.entityId).then(result =>
              result.data.forEach(unitTenancy => this.addPropertyContactsToAutocompleteItems(unitTenancy.unit.propertyId)));
          });
        });
        break;
      case 'UNIT':
        unitService.get(this.entityId).then(result =>
          this.addPropertyContactsToAutocompleteItems(result.data.propertyId));
        break;
      case 'PROPERTY':
        this.addPropertyContactsToAutocompleteItems(this.entityId);
        break;
    }
  },
```

I am focusing specifically on this line:

```
        if (recipients.length) {
          defaultTags.push(this.setText({description: this.$t('tenants'), recipients}));
        }
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. When clicking the button do you want to add all fruits in the `fruits` array into basket or a single one?

Comment: Not quite following what you're asking either. If you want to loop over all your available fruits, use `v-for="fruit in fruits"`. If you want to loop over fruits in your basket, use `v-for="fruit in basket"`.

Comment: I added some more to my question. I thought I would make it easier for people by using a more simple code example, so now I included a piece of my own code as well.

Answer (score 0):

It outputs the entire fruit items because you are pushing the whole array into the basket array, not the actual items. Saying `basket` is an array of array, not an array of fruits.

```js
// Instead of this
this.basket.push(this.fruits); // [['Orange', 'Apple']]

// Use array destructuring
this.basket.push(...this.fruits); // ['Orange, 'Apple']
// Or concat
this.basket.concat(this.fruits); // ['Orange, 'Apple']
```